# After install IOS X El capitan I get some php errors and warnings

Tags: php, osx-elcapitan

I was using in my MacBook pro Yosemite, I upgraded to "El capitan" and now when I run in terminal php -i, I get some error and warnings.

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ioncube_loader_dar_5.5.so:  dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ioncube_loader_dar_5.5.so, 9): image not found
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.5.30
```

I tried to this:

```
 brew reinstall imagemagick
 brew link imagemagick
```

Also I added in /etc/php.ini this line:
     extension=imagick.so

For ioncube I did that:

```
brew unlink php55-ioncubeloader
brew install homebrew/php/php55-ioncubeloader
```

and the of course restart apache: sudo apachectl restart, but same results.

In Yosemite, 2 days ago everything was fine.